# IdentityServer4 how to access parameters in /connect/token request

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to create an IdentityServer4 solution (ASP.NET Core 3.1, Entity Framework Core) that is multi-tenant with a database-per-tenant model.

I start by passing acr_values tenant:tenantname. I then extract this from the request and dynamically get the proper connection string.

However, I eventually end up with this OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.

It happens as it attempt to read/write to PersistedGrants. I can tell by the time I get to the /connect/token endpoint where this occurs, I lose all track of the tenant name in the request. It's no longer in a query string, body, nothing... but I also don't have an authenticated user at this point to look at a claim.

What would be a good way to access this information to properly connect to the database for that final request?

I've attached just my EntityFrameworkCore db context configuration, because that's where all the magic is happening.

```cs
            services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            {
                // Get the standard default connection string
                string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

                // Inspect the HTTP Context
                var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

                // function to parse the tenant name from the acr (i.e. tenant:testtenant)
                string GetTenantNameFromRequest(HttpRequest request)
                {
                    string ParseTenantName(string acrValues)
                    {
                        return Regex.Match(acrValues, @"tenant:(?<TenantName>[^\s]*)").Groups["TenantName"]?.Value;
                    }

                    if (request == null || request.Query?.Count == 0)
                        return null;

                    // Get the possible queries for the tenant name to show up in
                    var acr = request.Query["acr_values"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acr))
                        return ParseTenantName(acr);

                    var returnUrl = request.Query["returnUrl"]; // Web MVC
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                    {
                        NameValueCollection returnUrlQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(returnUrl);
                        return ParseTenantName(returnUrlQuery["acr_values"]);
                    }

                    var redirectUri = request.Query["redirect_uri"]; // OIDC Client (WinForms)
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri))
                    {
                        NameValueCollection returnUrlQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(returnUrl);
                        return ParseTenantName(returnUrlQuery["acr_values"]);
                    }

                    //  connect/token does not include any information about the authentication request

                    return null;
                }

                string tenantName = GetTenantNameFromRequest(httpContext?.Request);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantName) && string.Compare(tenantName, "localhost", true) != 0)
                {
                    // call catalog to get the tenant connection information
                    var tenantLookupService = serviceProvider.GetService<TenantLookupService>();
                    connectionString = tenantLookupService.GetTenantConnectionStringAsync(tenantName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }

                // connect with the proper connection string.
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o =>
                {
                    o.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                });
            });
```

here is the IdentityServer4 setup code, though I don't think it's relevant to this issue.

```cs
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
            })
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
            .AddOperationalStore<MyAppDbContext>(options =>
            { 
                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            })
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

Update... trying new method of accessing via cookie

```cs
            services.AddDbContext<MyAppDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
            {
                string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

                var httpContext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

                string GetTenantNameFromRequest(HttpContext context)
                {
                    string ParseTenantName(string acrValues)
                    {
                        return Regex.Match(acrValues, @"tenant:(?<TenantName>[^\s]*)").Groups["TenantName"]?.Value;
                    }

                    var request = context?.Request;

                    if (request == null) //|| request.Query?.Count == 0)
                        return null;

                    // Get the possible queries for the tenant name to show up in
                    var acr = request.Query["acr_values"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acr))
                    { 
                        string tenantName = ParseTenantName(acr);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantName))
                        {
                            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
                            cookieOptions.IsEssential = true;
                            cookieOptions.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                            cookieOptions.Secure = true;
                            cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);
                            context.Response.Cookies.Append("signin-tenant", tenantName, cookieOptions);
                        }

                        return tenantName;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string tenantName = context.Request.Cookies["signin-tenant"];
                        return tenantName;
                    }
                }

                string tenantName = GetTenantNameFromRequest(httpContext);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantName) && string.Compare(tenantName, "localhost", true) != 0)
                {
                    var tenantLookupService = serviceProvider.GetService<TenantLookupService>();
                    connectionString = tenantLookupService.GetTenantConnectionStringAsync(tenantName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }

                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o =>
                {
                    o.EnableRetryOnFailure();
                });
            });

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: It will not work this way. You need to handle your tenancy inside your DbContext. There you choose the connection string. Not inside startup.

Comment: Hi Dennis, it actually does work well this way in ASP.NET Core 3. This gets called each time a connection is made, even from within startup. Might even have been since 2.x? Not sure. In any case, it works, and works well. Just need a way to get the requested tenant out in the /connect/token call.

Comment: Just to be explicit about which steps are being taken, which grant type are you using? I imagine authorization_code since you mention using the IPersistedGrantStore implementation in the core/connect/token endpoint. Also, how do you know the problem is reading/writing with the PersistedGrantStore?

Comment: Yes, I'm using authorization code.

I guess I'm not 100% sure that's were the issue is, I'm basing this on a couple of things though.

The message I receive...
OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.

When I look this up, it seems to be from people using InMemory operational store. So taking that information, and knowing that on localhost this works fine, where I point to a localdb that does have the same user in the db, it works. So I did make an assumption there :)

Comment: And I'm watching these requests in debug and can see that final POST /connect/token and that's where I lose track of any information to identity the tenant. Surely there must be some way to push a value from start/finish-- I'm sure I'm far from the only person to attempt EF database-per-tenant with identityserver :-|

Comment: The only way to persist this kind of information, knowing you can trust it, is to add it as claims. Set claims like tenant_id, tenant_name, db_id for the user or add a custom ProfileService. On login pass acr_values, making sure you hit the correct (user) database and after that use the information from the claims.

Comment: Hi Ruard, I currently do utilize ProfileService to add to the claim. The problem is the call to POST /connect/token does not have an authenticated user.

Comment: I think I understand more of what's going on now. When you registered MyAppDbContext to be your IPersistedGrantStore implementation with 'AddOperationalStore', IdentityServer now will run the configuration specified in 'AddDbContext' whenever it needs an IPersistedGrantStore. Since the token request doesn't have acr_values the DbContext can't actually determine which database to connect to when validating the authorization code and will fail the code redemption. Maybe you can set the acr_values needed in a protected cookie upon arrival to the login page.

Comment: Thanks, Randy. Yes, it sounds like you've pretty much got your head wrapped around the problem. Hmm... that's an interesting idea. By protected cookie you mean...? Just a cookie i trust from my server? Or is there another concept I'm missing?

Comment: Ahh man. That doesn't seem to work either :-| The cookies are cleared out of the request at /connect/token. Must happen as a result of the ASP.NET Identity sign in? Not sure why that request has no cookies. Updated original post with how I'm trying to access this. That cookie is there for every other request... just not that final one

Comment: It seems that any request sent by IdentityServer cannot get access to the cookie I save. Cookies like this are a bit out of my wheelhouse. For example requests with paths such as /.well-known/openid-configuration
/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks and of course /connect/token can't read my cookie. Tried SameSiteMode.None as well, no change I make to the cookie seems to have any effect.

Comment: It seems you are using the same database (per tenant) for ConfigurationStore, OperationalStore and UserStore. Since the first two stores have nothing to do with tenants (this is client/resource configuration), you should use a global database that is accesable for all tenants. The UserStore however, can be set per tenant (AddEntityFrameworkStores). This way you should be able to login (no invalid grant type errors) and complete the login step, persisting the db info or reference in a claim.

Comment: Hi Ruard, so you're suggesting the PersistedGrants and the OperationalStore can be in a global database? My client configuration is all in memory as that will be global and unchanged. I suppose that would be easiest, but I thought that was no good. I'll give it a shot as well!

Comment: Well, crap. This fixes the issue with the invalid grants, but then by the time I get to the ProfileService implementation which is in this same call, I still don't have what I need so ProfileService isn't connecting to the right database :-|

Comment: Then you'll have to persist the data in the general store. You can add a 'login tenant table', persist the information identified by some id, token, state, a combination of factors or whatever can uniquely idenitifiy the user and save the tenant id. When accessing the ProfileService use this data to set the correct connectionstring. Since this is a tenant system, I would use middleware to set this information on each request so it is injected in the stores automatically.

Comment: Going back to what I said about the cookie, I was a bit confused and forgot the token exchange isn't typically done by the user who logged in. The request is usually made by the server and therefore a cookie would not be present. The only way to persist this information is to potentially set a cookie manually (on the server side) to relay information about the tenant, or find a scheme where the authorization code itself could indicate which tenant is used (this would have to be done by injection an AuthorizationCodeStore that generates tokens in a unique, tenant-identifiable format)

Comment: Hi @Randy, i think if i were to store this in a session (is this what you meant by server side cookie?) I still have no identifiable way to grab the correct one back out. Best case it would be a timing thing, which could really get messed up if multiple people were logging in at the same time I suspect. Like I said, I can't imagine this is the first time someone has done db per tenant with identityserver? Surely i'm missing something simple :(

Comment: Not a session cookie, but a cookie indicating the tenant that would be sent by the relying party. Alternatively this could be in the form of a new header as well. I suggest this because the relying party is the one sending the token request here. Another way that you can convey more contextual information for the token request *without* involvement of the relying party is making the authorization code sent to the relying party have information in it regarding the tenant, kind of like how the 'state' is used to hold information in the ASP.NET Core's implementation of the OpenID Connect protocol

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Hi I have achieved this by adding below code

```
 string acr_values = context?.ValidatedRequest?.Raw.Get("acr_values");
```

Moreover if you want to inject acr_value in your client, you can inject it through it

```
  context.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters.Add("acr_value", "tenantCode:xyz");
```

Comment: I tried this and any other method to get to that. The fact is when you get to /connect/token, those acr values are nowhere to be found. I ended up implementing an endpointrouter and inject the tenant name right into the path of any IS4 endpoint.

Comment: Hi @Nate can you please provide how you have provided, tenantId. I always get value of tenantId.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved and was confirmed by leastprivilege. If you need to access tenant name through the whole flow, acr_values is not the way to go.